# Memory consumption with jQuery hover() method

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery hover() to animate div.

But when I mouse in/out every time,the more memory is used (check from chrome taskmanager)

I tried to wait 5-10 minutes but memory not release

Can someone give me some tips to improve this ?
I am new in web develop

Here is sample https://jsfiddle.net/xr73fsL3/

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#/" class="f_i">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="f_d">2015-11-25T19:40:48Z</div>
        </div>
        <div class="f_c ">
            <span>Best Buy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
        </div>
   </a>
    <div>
        <span class="s">Hello</span>
    </div>
   </li>
</ul>

$('.f_i').hover(
    function(){ 
        var $o=$(this).children(".overlay");
        $o.stop(true,true).animate({top: "+=100%"});
        $(this).children(".f_c").stop(true,true).animate({left: "+=100%"},800);
    }
   ,function(){ 
        var $o=$(this).children(".overlay");
        $o.stop(true,true).css('top','');
        $(this).children(".f_c").stop(true,true).css('left','');
    });
```

Comment: Try declaring named functions: https://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/xr73fsL3/1/

Comment: thank you . I tried but it still use more and more memory when I mouse in/out. I will try in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stack Overflow! First of all, did you check this [famous link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/) from CSS tricks?

Adjust your code to look exactly like `Dequeue` example from the link and you should have no performance and memory issues.